How to get video duration if the file is uploaded using PLupload?
Using PLUPLOAD, I need to fetch the duration, if the uploaded file is a video?
PLUPload documentation didn't helped, I see no option to fetch the duration in javascript with Plupload. Is there any known method or options to fetch the duration in plupload

PLUPload just uploads files. It doesn't know (or care) about the type of files. Why would it have special information about video files?
